# How can i remake the return from Google search api?

Tags: api, web

How can i use Google search api to get like on the google engine, title of website,a short description and URL. Is it possible?
   I tried the api but it gives me only some information that doesn`t have a url or title to a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Google shopping api, you can retrieve the title, short description and url. I've achieved this in a c# application where it returns a json file from the url below and parse over it.

You need a `apiId` to start with.

Using this url you can add search parameters after the q, in this example just searching for digital camera.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q=digital+camera
```

See http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html
for more details

Comment: I will try it, i also have another idee, i started to work at it last night and is better then google api. the url i use for the search is http://ajax[dot]googleapis[dot]com/ajax/services/search/ but know when i run the script it gives me : object(stdClass)#23 (3) { ["responseData"]=> NULL ["responseDetails"]=> string(65) "Quota Exceeded. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/websearch" ["responseStatus"]=> int(403) } object . I`m thinking of sending the refferer to google, but i will try the googleapis.com/shopping and i wil return with an answer. Thank you.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/ has deprecated so that could be the reason why you can't use it and its limited to a number of responses, "The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I have enough information, but I find the Google Custom Search API reference page has the reference JSON/ATOM examples:
https://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/reference.html

This query will get you started:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={YOURAPIKEY}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&q=st%20olaf

Does this get you started?

Take care!
speeves

Comment: I have looked at it before posting the question,the limit of results returned by google is 10. And for example if i search for php manuals it only give me this: Php Manual 2011 and more like this, no url,no description,no title of website. Maybe i don`t use it how it needs,but this is what i am getting and it doesn`t help me a lot